# PreparedStatement - executeBatch

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using executeBatch for writing into database. **Batch size is 50.**

```
long startt = System.currentTimeMillis();
da.writeAll(batchRaiseRecords);
LoggerClient.writeError("DML write sendDML - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startt) + " - size - " + batchRaiseRecords.size(),"");
```

Now, this time taken by this operation varies from *0.2 to 6 seconds*. My doubt is why is this much variation?

```
Line 2246: DML write sendDML - 362555602 - size - 50, 
Line 3960: DML write sendDML - 609145666 - size - 50, 
Line 6034: DML write sendDML - 1398866678 - size - 50, 
Line 7676: DML write sendDML - 324071619 - size - 50, 
Line 9398: DML write sendDML - 492674501 - size - 50, 
Line 11180: DML write sendDML - 632663209 - size - 50, 
Line 14926: DML write sendDML - 6776384464 - size - 50, 
Line 16542: DML write sendDML - 384737523 - size - 50, 
Line 17896: DML write sendDML - 287436213 - size - 50, 
Line 18730: DML write sendDML - 206414079 - size - 50, 
Line 19548: DML write sendDML - 288492245 - size - 50, 
Line 20382: DML write sendDML - 310753856 - size - 50, 
Line 21212: DML write sendDML - 695180583 - size - 50, 
Line 22466: DML write sendDML - 232818139 - size - 50, 
Line 23360: DML write sendDML - 246089140 - size - 50, 
Line 24420: DML write sendDML - 192751420 - size - 50,
```

I tried this operation many a times, and results are almost similar.

Why this much variation in same operation **executeBatch()**?

**EDIT :** DML is used for writing to MySql database. And there is only one client.

Comment: Which JDBC driver and database are you using? How many concurrent clients are there? Also, this might be a candidate for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What is `da.writeAll()` ? The delay may come from `LoggerClient.writeError()`. Hard to say, not enough information.

Comment: edited question. And Logger.writeError is not causing problem.

Comment: Is this a local database or remote database? Also what about the size (As in the number of chars/bytes) per batch. If this is running against the same database/tables, then only network latency / Actual byte size of the payload might be causing this and noithing else.

Comment: Are you performing this work from within a transaction, either explicitly or implicitly?